# How to run numpy log in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm really new to writing python classes. Basically, I'm trying to write a class that will be used in an sklearn pipeline. The class needs to add two attributes to an existing data frame by modifying some existing attributes.

1. The new attributes will be a log transformation of an existing column, and
2. The product of two other Attributes multiplied together. Here is what I have:

code:

```
import BaseEstimator and TransformerMixIn
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

population_ix, A_PM10_ix, A_PM25_ix = 15, 2, 3

class CombinedAttributes(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        log_pop = np.log(X[:,population_ix])
        pm = X[:, A_PM10_ix] * X[:,A_PM25_ix]
        return np.c_[X, log_pop, pm]

attr_adder = CombinedAttributes()
env_extra_attribs = attr_adder.transform(environment.values)
```

This is the error message I get:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-e138b3c2e517> in <module>()
      1 attr_adder = CombinedAttributes()
----> 2 env_extra_attribs = attr_adder.transform(environment.values)

<ipython-input-65-e4aac1c1930b> in transform(self, X, y)
     11         return self
     12     def transform(self, X, y=None):
---> 13         log_pop = np.log(X[:,population_ix])
     14         pm = X[:, A_PM10_ix] * X[:,A_PM25_ix]
     15         return np.c_[X, log_pop, pm]

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'log'</code>
```

My question is how do I get the log transform to work in this.

Also,I'm also not 100% sure about how I included a pass statement in the `init` def. Again, this is totally new and I'm having trouble finding tutorials that I can understand.

Any assistance would be appreciated, thanks,

Comment: have you shadowed `np` to a float value? That is a possible explanation

Comment: If you try to create an [mcve] you probably find your error yourself ;-)

Comment: @Alfe I'm not too sure what else to give you guys, honestly. I'm newer to this, and it seems like it would be a huge amount of info based on the link you posted...Can you help me out by telling me what else should be included specifically? Again, I do want to get better at this, so its a serious question. How would I make something like this reproducible? Posting it on Github so you have the data also?

Comment: @EdChum Hi, Ed. Unfortunately I can verify that this is not the case. As I asked 
Alfe, I'm not too sure what else I should include here to show you guys, this is part of a larger notebook...I'm happy to try and fix the post to meet the standards, but I'm a bit confused as to the best way to do that...

Comment: Try to reduce the amount of code as much as possible by removing line per line, while making sure that you still get the error.

Comment: Or start the other way round:  Make a minimal script which contains the line you currently get your error in.  I'm pretty sure it will not show the error.  Then extend that bit by bit to come closer to your original source, and at some point you will introduce the error.

Comment: You should also try to find out how in your environment you can reach the real stack trace and post it here (because this can give some clue about what's going on).  Currently we only see `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'log'</code>` which isn't very helpful.

Comment: Thank you both. I will try to revise. I appreciate you taking the time to help me out ;-)

Comment: What's the shape and dtype of `X`?  I suspect it is object dtype.

Answer (score 1):

The error message basically says that you are trying to call a `.log()` method is an object that is a `float`.  Since you do that only on the object `np`, I consider that you accidentally overwrite your imported module `np` somewhere.  You didn't provide all your code, especially no MCVE, so I only can guess that you maybe have an assignment to `np` prior to your executed code.

I suggest you scan your code for such a line or otherwise provide your code in you question or create an MCVE which shows the problem so we can reproduce it.

Comment: I totally see why it looks that way, but its not the case, unfortunately. I'm not sure how else to edit this post to give you guys what you need...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you "overwrote" the imported numpy module with a `float` value.
Search your code for something like:

```
np = 5.4
```

or any other kind of `np =`.
Also make sure you correctly import numpy with `import numpy as np` and that **did NOT include any starred imports from unknown/self-written modules** with something like `from module_name import *`.
This might "overwrite" your numpy module import, if any variable named `np` is contained in that module.

In general you should avoid importing modules with `from module_name import *`. This will almost always cause trouble.

Comment: Hi @Scotty1-, I can verify this is not the case. Thanks for your response though.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `environment.values`, or `X` inside the function is an object dtype array.

```
In [195]: x = np.array([1.2, 2.3], object)
In [196]: np.sqrt(x)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-196-0b43c7e80401> in <module>()
----> 1 np.sqrt(x)

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
In [197]: (x+x)/2
Out[197]: array([1.2, 2.3], dtype=object)
In [198]: np.log(x)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-198-de666c833898> in <module>()
----> 1 np.log(x)

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'log'
```

I elaborate on this in another recent answer, [AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'sqrt'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54672568/attributeerror-series-object-has-no-attribute-sqrt/54675746#54675746)